# Careers company ad, logo obscuring banner

Tags: feature-request, bug, status-bydesign, jobs, advertising

Well, I'm uncertain if this is truly a bug or not, or if its just Imgur who happened to 'mess up' here, but there appears to be a slight issue with SE's handling of career company logos, and their banners:

[image: Logo blocking banner]
[image]

As I'm sure can be seen from the image, the logo blocks the banner text.  One solution is to simply move the thing, or it could (maybe) be removed altogether..  though I do realize that this would likely cause complaints.

On the possibility that it cannot be moved, maybe the companies could be alerted of how such an ad would look.. or even offer the possibility to not display the logo.. or something else, if anything.  I'm honestly wholly unfamiliar with how that side of things work, so sorry there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Company page ads overlay the companies logo over top the header image on their company page. This is just a situation where the company used a header image with text which we don't suggest.

Comment: To clarify, since I'm still unsure, is the company actually notified of how things will look?  Your answer seems to suggest that, but I'd like to be sure.

Comment: Yup. They are shown a mockup of how it looks at the time of purchase and if they look at their listings, the same issue applies.

Comment: Alright then; thank you for the clarification.